# Notification message from AudioTrack stream

Tags: java, android, pcm

I've implemented a PCM decoder that writes to an `AudioTrack` object.

Everything seems great, however, I need to get some sort of notification from the `AudioTrack` object when the last written chunk has stopped playing.

I've noticed that there are callback methods such as `setNotificationMarkerPosition,` however, I couldn't find any extensive documentation as how to use them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hi chaoz, how did u implement PCM decoder? i am looking for an PCM decoder to decode an audio, any help will be greatly useful to me.

Answer (score 2):

To get an `AudioTrack` callback, you could set a marker callback or use the periodic callback. I've seen reports of problems with the marker, so you may want to try both.

For the marker callback, first call `setNotificationMarkerPosition` with whatever frame number you want a call for.

For a periodic callback, instead call `setPositionNotificationPeriod` and it will call every *x* frames.

Either way, you'll need to call `setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener` to register the callback. This will call two methods, `onMarkerReached` if it reaches a marker, or `onPeriodicNotification` every set number of frames. You can choose to use one or the other, or both. Both callbacks refer the instance of `AudioTrack` you used to set it.

By default, it will call back in the same thread the `AudioTrack` instance was created. Alternatively, you can pass a handler when you register the callbacks to send it to another thread.